# Compiler showing struct.error: ushort format requires 0 <= number <= (0x7fff * 2 + 1) in zipfile.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, build, zip

I'm trying to build tensorflow with yacto project, during build I started to get `zip does not support timestamps before 1980`. On searching I found that we can fix this issue by adding `datetime=(1980,1,1,0,0)`.
When I added the above code in Zipfile.py, I started to get another issue of `struct.error: ushort format requires 0 <= number <= (0x7fff * 2 + 1)` in `FileHeader` method of zipfile.py

Below are the things I have already tried:

```
file = open(filename, 'w')
file.close()
```

and

```
timestamp = time.mktime((1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
os.utime(filename, (timestamp, timestamp))
```

and I also changed the `H` with `L`. Still the same issue.

Please find the error below:

```
self.fp.write(zinfo.FileHeader(zip64))
|   File "/home/ch/05-07/build/BUILD/work/raspberrypi4/tensorflow/1.13.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 429, in FileHeader
|     header = struct.pack(structFileHeader, stringFileHeader,
| struct.error: ushort format requires 0 <= number <= (0x7fff * 2 + 1)
```

I also tried to `touch` all the files in dist, still I get the same error. Has someone faced the similar issue and found a solution for this?

Comment: This is an XY problem, you should describe the original problem in detail, and usualyl with date issues, make sure your computer's date is correctly set.